# Intern functional testing: skip a suite/test

Tags: javascript, intern

I'm writing some functional tests using Intern/Leadfoot. These tests are end-to-end tests (called also stories) and between them there kind of data dependency. With that I mean that a test (ie. test2) will fail if the previous test (test1) did not complete successfully. So in order to avoid running tests that fail for sure I want to skip them (or part of them). Thus, I wonder if there a way to achieve that.

Consider that all test.js files are like the one below:

```
define([
    "require",
    "intern", 
    "intern!object",
    "../../support/executor/executor"],
    function(require, intern, registerSuite, Executor) {

    var executor;
    var steps = [

        // set of actions, 
        // like login, click this button,
        // then assert that ....
    ];

    registerSuite(function() {
        return {
            setup: function() {
                executor = new Executor(this.remote, steps.slice(0));
            },

            "Test 1": function() {
                return executor.run();
            },
        };
    });
});
```

This means that each js file is a suite that contains only one test. In other words, it's like I wanna skip all remaining suites, if a previous one failed.

Answer (score 6):

The Intern docs specify a this.skip method that is available for unit tests (https://theintern.io/docs.html#Intern/4/docs/docs%2Fwriting_tests.md/skipping-tests-at-runtime) which also works for functional/e2e tests.

```
"skipped test":function(){
    this.skip('skipping this');
}
```

They also specify a grep-regex option for skipping tests via the config (https://theintern.io/docs.html#Intern/4/docs/docs%2Fwriting_tests.md/skipping-tests-at-runtime).